# Police Interrogation Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

I have tried so hard to solve this puzzle. But I cannot get my head around it. I have attempted to eliminate the lies and I have come up with Dave as the criminal. But I do not know if it is the correct answer.

Here is the puzzle:

The police are interrogating five suspects after a bank robbery. Each of them makes two statements, but it turns out that only five of these statements are true. Can you work out who committed the crime?

- Alan said: ‘It wasn’t Ben. It was Carl’
- Ben said: ‘It wasn’t Alan. It was Dave’
- Carl said: ‘It wasn’t Dave. It wasn’t Ben either’
- Dave said: ‘It wasn’t Eddie. It was Alan’
- Eddie said: ‘It wasn’t Carl. It was Derek’

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assumption: One of these five suspects committed the robbery alone.

Consider all five possible suspects, and which statements are true or false as a result:

> It was Alan -> TF FF TT TT TF (6)

> It was Ben -> FF TF TF TF TF (4)

> It was Carl -> TT TF TT TF FF (6)

> It was Dave -> TF TT FT TF T? (6 or 7, depending on whether "Derek" was supposed to be "Dave")

> It was Eddie -> TF TF TT FF TF (5) - this is the only one fitting the puzzle statement, so it must be the solution.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.